# How to create a .npmrc file from the .npmrc.template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, build

There is a [project](https://github.com/internxt/drive-desktop) and I'm going to build it. so there are certain actions to do first but IDK anything about npmrc files. how to do these steps which are described below? Well mostly I haven't gotten how to do the first two steps

Create a .npmrc file from the .npmrc.template example provided in the repo.

Replace TOKEN with your own Github Personal Access Token with read:packages permission ONLY

Use yarn to install project dependencies.

Comment: What in the description do you find hard?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just copy the file, it should do the job

```sh
cp .npmrc.template .npmrc
```

Then you can open and edit `.npmrc` and run `yarn` after you're done with your edits.

Comment: thanks, but why should I copy that?  there are already  .nmprc and .npmrc.template files

Comment: @Shaka92 The project you've linked doesn't have a `.npmrc` file